# Make Component Reusable with Typescript in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo

Building a React app, I want to make my code as DRY as possible. I started to use Typescript for the first time in this project and I am confronted with the problem of reusability of my components where JSX can be the same for different cases but types and interfaces change.

Here is a real example : The code below is a React component built with TypeScript, Apollo / GraphQL, and Redux. It returns a table of all football teams in my DB, fetched from a backend API.

The thing is, I'd like to use this same component to display a table of games, a table of players, etc.

And I am stuck, for example, with my `Team` interface. Each team only has an `id` and a `name`; but each game has a `date`, a `homeTeam` and an `awayTeam, a`score`, etc.

Hence how can I manage my interfaces and my types so that I can reuse this component ?

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setView, toggleDeleteElemModal } from '../../redux/actions';

import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { Query } from 'react-apollo';
import { ApolloError } from 'apollo-client';

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faInfo, faEdit, faTrash } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

interface SectionTableProps {
  setView: typeof setView
  toggleDeleteElemModal : typeof toggleDeleteElemModal
}

interface Team {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

interface Data {
  allTeams?: Team[];
}

interface SectionTableQueryProps {
    allTeams: Team[];
    error?: ApolloError;
    loading: boolean;
}

const GET_ALL_TEAMS = gql`
  query {
    allTeams {
      id
      name
    }
  }
`;

class SectionTableQuery extends Query<Data, {}> {}

const SectionTable = (props: SectionTableProps) => (
  <table className="table table-hover table-responsive">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
      <SectionTableQuery query={GET_ALL_TEAMS}>
      {({ data: { allTeams = [] } = {}, error, loading }) => {
        if (loading) {
          return <tbody><tr><td>LOADING</td></tr></tbody>
        };
        if (error !== undefined) {
          return <tbody><tr><td>ERROR</td></tr></tbody>
        };
        return (
          <tbody>
            {allTeams.map((team: Team) => (
                <tr key={team.id}>
                  <th scope="row">{team.id}</th>
                  <td>{team.name}</td>
                  <td className="d-flex justify-content-between">
                  <div onClick={() => props.setView("info")}>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faInfo} />
                  </div>
                  <div onClick={() => props.setView("edit")}>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEdit} />
                  </div>
                  <div onClick={() => props.toggleDeleteElemModal()}>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash} />
                  </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>

            ))}
          </tbody>
        );
      }}
    </SectionTableQuery>
  </table>
)

const mapDispatchToProps = { setView, toggleDeleteElemModal }

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SectionTable);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Generic types for JSX components for this behaviour.

```
class SectionTableQuery extends Query<P, {}> {} // where P is the generic prop
```

The `SectionTable` declaration would have to take in this generic `P` interface from it's parent and while rendering `SectionTableQuery`:

```
const SectionTable<P> = (props: SectionTableProps) => (
  <SectionTableQuery<P> query={props.query}>  // Assuming you want the query to change, that would be passed as a prop too
  ...
  </SectionTableQuery>
);
```

While rendering `SectionTable`, the parent can choose to pass in the props that he/she wants

```
<SectionTable<ITeam> ... />
<SectionTable<IPlayer> ... />
```

This is a general approximation of what you would have to do, seems like there might be more than one generic type you want to pass in depending on the query (`IData` for what is returned from the query and `IItem` for the item itself`)

PS: Generic Components is available from [Typescript 2.9](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help ! Indeed, Generics is the magic I was looking for.